# Counting permutation cycle types in $S_n$

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

Consider the sym group $S_4$,

We write the elements of $S_4$ in a given "form" such as
\begin{align*}
e = (1)(2)(3)(4) &\sim 1,1,1,1 \\
(12)(34) &\sim 2,2 \\
(123)(4) &\sim 3,1 
\end{align*}

Note that the number indicate the lenght of a cycle.

Also, notice that
$(123)(4)$, $(124)(3)$ and $(234)(1)$ (also their inverses) are in the form of 
$3,1$

So here are the list for $S_4$:
\begin{align*}
&1,1,1,1\\
&2,1,1 \\
&2,2 \\
&3,1 \\
&4 
\end{align*}

There are $5$.

For $S_5$:
\begin{align*}
&1,1,1,1,1 \\
&2,1,1,1 \\
&2,2,1, \\
&3,1,1 \\
&3,2 \\
&4,1 \\
&5 
\end{align*}

There are $7$.

For $S_6$, there are $11$.

Now, I'm trying to make a fomula or a way to determine how many "forms" in $S_n$, for all $n$. However, I can't figure it out..

Please help me with this problem I just made.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Some terminology: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Cycle_type_of_a_permutation

Comment: Ohh so it has a name haha tnk u..

Answer (score 3):

Note that cycle types in $S_n$ can be viewed as unordered integer partitions of $n$ and vice versa, hence the answer is $p\left(n\right)$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function)). Unfortunately there's no nice formula for the output of the partition function, but its generating function is quite nice and it is easy to look up values for small $n$.

Comment: Ohh. Thnk so much.. More power !